# Getting Started with IronRuby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ironruby

Can somebody point me to a tutorial and/or Getting Started document to get IronRuby running Rails?  I'm particularly interested in a detailed, step-by-step reference, *not* general guidelines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like there finally is one:

http://www.ironruby.net/Documentation/Rails

Answer (score 20):

IronRuby already 'runs' Rails today. We demo'd it running Rails back at RailsConf 08. That said, we have a lot of fit and finish work to do on IronRuby to get it to a state where it can run Rails *well*.

Where we're lacking right now is:

Startup speed - this is critical for a decent experience when working with Rails - especially if you're running unit tests. Right now it takes 26s to startup Rails.

Working set - we're currently at 100MB for a 'hello world' Rails app vs. 30MB for MRI.

We're actually doing fine on throughput - once we're compiled things run reasonably well.

We're moving towards an adaptive compilation strategy where we interpret by default and compile the hot spots that we find. This will make the developer experience *much* better. We will also have an ahead-of-time compilation mode (perhaps in conjunction with NGEN and intelligent caching) down the road which may be better than the adaptive compilation strategy.

Comment: I'm aware of that.  As I said, though, I'm looking for a step-by-step reference to get Rails up-and-running on IronRuby.  It's the difference between telling your wife "the car has a spare tire" and showing her how to change it.

Comment: Dude-- don't talk to John Lam like that. It's John Lam.

Comment: @Michael Haren - Circular Argument is Circular. (-1 btw, I agree with @GuyBehindTheGuy)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to disappoint but I think you'll have to write the tutorial yourself. Unless I've missed something, IronRuby doesn't run Rails yet, although they've demonstrated some aspects running.

According to the [IronRuby home page](http://www.ironruby.net/) they're at about 71% complete on the RubySpecs core package, which is probably still some way from enough to go from `rails <projectName` right through to `ironruby script/server`

When IR runs Rails, I think we may hear about it. Or rather, we may have to shut ourselves in isolation chambers to avoid hearing about it...

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of nice "step by step", for beginners: http://www.ironruby.net/Samples_and_tutorials

Comment: Nice, but I don't see any references to rails...

Comment: True, but should be some deep in there :)

Comment: IronRuby can't run Rails yet, so that's not too surprising.

Comment: Once again... 404 now...

Comment: @shytikov, I think their page is down at the moment.